# Set & Clear Interval In JQuery For Running Script Every X Seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that check for messages received by members of my site but I need it to run every 60 seconds or so.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
var yourid = <?php echo json_encode($yourid); ?>;
function fetch_messages(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "php/check-messages.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id : yourid },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#headerInbox').addClass("headerAlert");
        }
    });
}
$(function(){
    fetch_messages();
});
});
</script>
```

This works fine on page entry and runs the #headerInbox addclass but I need it to run every 60 seconds and then stop when a success is found.How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use setinterval()

Comment: Better would be to use a timeout and recall a new one instead of using an interval, just in case. But with 60s delay, an interval should be fine. BTW, what do you mean by: `when a success is found`? When success callback is called or what?

Comment: @AlienArrays you forgot a zero

Comment: If you do a `clearInterval` during the `success` callback, as the answers below both do, then the ajax request will only happen once (unless the request errors which isn't likely)

Comment: @AlienArrays That is just totally wrong.  You don't give intervals or timeouts a name - creating them returns an ID that you then pass as a parameter when you want to clear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
{

var yourid = <?php echo json_encode($yourid); ?>;
var fetchInterval;

function fetch_messages(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "php/check-messages.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id : yourid },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#headerInbox').addClass("headerAlert");
            clearInterval(fetchInterval);
        }
    });
}

fetchInterval = setInterval(fetch_messages, 60000);
});
</script>
```

This should work - creates an interval "fetchInterval" which will call fetch_messages every 60 secs, then on success clear the interval.

Comment: Then i guess timeout option with less than 60s of ajax method should be set because here if the request made more than 60s to fire an error, this could be an issue

Comment: @A.Wolff Do you know how the Ajax can be run on page load and THEN every 60 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to achieve this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_messages(){
    var $interval = setInterval( function () {
        var yourid = <?php echo json_encode($yourid); ?>;

        $.ajax({
            url: "php/check-messages.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id : yourid },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#headerInbox').addClass("headerAlert");

                clearInterval($interval);
            }
        });
    }, 60 * 1000);
}

$( function() {
    fetch_messages();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
{
var yourid = <?php echo json_encode($yourid); ?>;
function fetch_messages(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "php/check-messages.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id : yourid },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#headerInbox').addClass("headerAlert");
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
    });
}
var myTimer = setInterval(function(){fetch_messages()()},6000);
});
</script>
```